# jquery prev and next appearance

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using lightbox2.7.1 and I am unable to customize the next and previous button of it.I want to show the next and previous button always and not after hovering.can someone help me to about this. the next and previous button appears after hovering and I want them to show always here is my website http://davidblakemore.com/portfolio2.htm
I am not a jquery expert but can change the code if someone help me...

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in the lightbox.css file, `.lb-nav a.lb-next` and `.lb-nav a.lb-prev` both have an `opacity: 0;` 
You'll have to change it to:

```
.lb-nav a.lb-prev, .lb-nav a.lb-next {
    opacity:1;
}
```